# Generate an angular@16 project within nx workspace

Tags: angular, angular16, nomachine-nx, nx-monorepo, nx-workspace

I want to generate an angular project version 16 within nx workspace

but after writing "npx create-nx-workspace@latest my-monorepo --preset=angular@16" the project is empty i don't know why.(I got just some config files )